# An object or column name is missing or empty (0x80131904)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, exception, mdf

I'm getting this error when I try to use the button to restore the database:

> "An object or column name is missing or empty".

The thing is that I'm using offline database file (.mdf) and when I click ok on this error and press the restore button again, it works like a charm.
There's the code:

```
private void RestoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string database = con.Database.ToString();
    if (con.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    try
    {
        string sqlStmt2 = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [" + database + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
        SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt2, con);
        bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string sqlStmt3 = "USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE [" + database + "] FROM DISK='" + textBox2.Text + "'WITH REPLACE;";
        SqlCommand bu3 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt3, con);
        bu3.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string sqlStmt4 = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [" + database + "] SET MULTI_USER");
        SqlCommand bu4 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt4, con);
        bu4.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Database succesfully restored!");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

[There's the full error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q4rw.jpg)

Comment: I can provide the code for the backup thing, as well. The problem is that it is working at the 2nd attempt, after ignoring the exception thrown, when it shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Can you debug and see at what line exception is thrown?

Comment: Sure. The exception is thrown at the line 89, I mean where is the execute non query of bu2.

Comment: And in the debugger, what is the value of the statement being executed when the error is thrown?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C# debugging, I'm sorry. If you can give me some newbie advices, I'll be grateful.

Comment: in your connect string which database have you given as your one to connect to?

Comment: I've used the properties.settings.default.connectionstring, admitting there's only one database. There's the code: 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(system32.Properties.Settings.Default.bazadedateConnectionString);

Comment: Actually, I've solved the issue with try and catch. On the catch part, I've just told to click once more on the button and it works perfect now.